# Intersection products in Algebraic Geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory

I have seen two definitions of intersection product in Aglebraic Geometry so far: one using the Chow ring of a variety (as defined for example in *3264 and all that*, by Eisenbud and Harris) and the other one using sheaf cohomology (as defined for example in Vakil's notes, def. 20.1.1., or in Hartshorne's *Ample subvarieties of algebraic varieties*).

> How are these two definitions related?

If we take $D$ to be a nice effective divisor on our (smooth, projective...) variety $X$ and we take $Y$ to be an $s$-dimensional subvariety, do we have the following equality?

$$(D^s.Y)=\deg([D]^s [Y])$$

(The left hand side being the definition using sheaf cohomology and the right hand side the definition using algebraic cycles).

What if we take $s$ different divisors? Under what conditions do we have equality?

For example in the case of surfaces the two products should agree, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In section 20.3 Ravi Vakil gives hints as how to relate those two approaches, namely he mentions a surjective map (which becomes an isomorphism after tensoring with $\mathbb{Q}$) $$A_d(X) \to A_{d}^{'}(X)$$where the left hand side group is the usual Chow group and on the right - the group adapted to his approach throughout chapter 20. He mentions Fulton's book on Intersection Theory for these facts, namely examples 15.1.5 and theorems 18.2 and 18.3.